# React Button to set my all elements checked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, checked

I have the following scenario, i am mapping `files` with a Media Card Component

```
const [files, setFiles] = useState([]);

const thumbs = files.map((file, i) => (
    <MediaCard
        onClick={() => handleCardClick(i)}
        checked={file.checked}
    />
));
```

Then i have a method which make my MediaCard Component checked in case it is not.

```
const handleCardClick = (index) => {
    const newFiles = files.map((file, i) => {
        if (i === index) file.checked = !file.checked
        return file
    });
    setFiles(newFiles);
}
```

Now i need a `button` with a new method called for example `allSelection` which make `checked` all my files mapped in the `MediaCard` Component, how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the function you need:

```
const allSelection = () => {
  setFiles((files) =>
    files.map((file) => {
      file.checked = true;
      return file;
    })
  );
};
```

Comment: Or better `file.checked = checked;` where checked is the state of the checkbox that checks them all

Comment: @mplungjan but we should remember every time the `checkbox` state has changed we need to call the function again if we used `file.checked = checked;`

Comment: Ok, whatever the equivalent method is in React